# New Class Item in Visual Studio 2017 not detected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

**Note:** The newly added class/file was to a Xamarin.Android project, and referenced from another.

---

After adding a new class/file, `NewClass`/**NewClass.cs**, to a particular folder with the **Add > New Item** command, it wasn't detected by the compiler, which was indicated by the error:

> "The type or namespace 'NewClass' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference)?

**Note:** I made sure the new type was made public

The project that `NewClass` was added to built successfully.  It was in the referencing project where the error was occurring (in a separate namespace and assembly).

After cleaning the solution and first building the referenced project failed, I tried the following:

1. Copied the definition of `NewClass` into an existing file and commented original one in **NewClass.cs** - error fixed.
2. Switched definition back to original location by commenting out the copied definition and un-commenting the one in **NewClass.cs** - error returned.
3. Copied the definition of `NewClass` into another existing file and commented original one in **NewClass.cs** - error fixed.
4. Switched definition back to original location by commenting out the copied definition and un-commenting the one in **NewClass.cs** - error did not return.

**Is there a manual operation that can be performed to ensure that a newly added class is successfully discovered by the compiler?** Cleaning and rebuilding didn't work, nor did reopening the solution.

Comment: Have you made sure you're referencing the project where `NewClass` is defined in the project where `NewClass` is used? Also, have you made sure you `NewClass` was defined in appropriate namespace and that namespace was used in the file where you want to use `NewClass`?

Comment: @AlyEl-Haddad The definition of `NewClass` in **NewClass.cs** now works (for some reason), so yes, the syntax and semantics are correct.

Comment: It sounds very much like an issue with your namespace naming. Check if perhaps you've made a typo in namespaces.

Comment: @Sach I used **Add > New Item** on a particular folder to see if a namespace based on the folder structure would actually be generated, and it was (since consistency between folder structure and namespace is only a convention). I did this instead of copy and pasting and existing file (as usual) as a quick experiment.

Comment: I don't know if it's your case, but when adding a class to a folder, the namespace changes from default `Namespace` to `Namespace.FolderName`. Try remove the `.FolderName`

Comment: @Magnetron The namespace is correct. Everything now compiles just as is it was when `NewClass` / **NewClass.cs** was originally added.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you used a different template originally (other than `class`) and renamed, or something of the sort, so the build action is incorrect.

Right click on the file and hit `Properties`. In the Properties window, make sure `Build Action` is set to `Compile`.

As a last resort, copy your code, delete the file, add a new file with the same name, then paste the code back.

Comment: I did compare properties as a troubleshooting measure, and aside from "File Name" and "Full Path", they were all the same ("Build Action" is set *Compile*).

Comment: @sαmosΛris: I see. Did you make sure the file is part of the project?

Comment: It would be useful if you post a code sample of the class definition, the code where the compiler breaks, a snapshot of the VS solution Explorer tree and a snapshot of the File Properties window.

Comment: If I can replicate the issue in a sample solution then I will add some edits. I've already spent too much time on this post.